# Create windows app package for 8.1 from windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-10, win-universal-app

I have a bunch of devices we sideloaded our app onto that are running windows 8.1

I was having problems with our project after I upgraded my dev machine to windows 10 so I created a new project using the standard blank project template. I then reimported my html/js code and started fresh.

This took care of the issues I was having but apparently the new template is only for window 10 and greater.

When I try to sideload onto a windows 8.1 machine it throws an error saying element:m does not meet the spec inside my appx package manifest.

I looked at both spec's but nothing is jumping out as being wrong, although there are differences.

I can't seem to find in the windows doc's what to do. Has anyone tried this?

What I want to do is create an app package for windows 8.1 machines from my windows 10 machine using Visual Studio 2015

**Edited for clarity.**

Comment: Is it a windows 8.1 store app you are trying to side load?

Comment: Yes, it was a windows 8.1 store app. I had never released it on the store though, just sideloaded.  I started a fresh project in windows 10 and pulled the code over into it and the appx packages dont match up so when I try to deploy it on windows 8.1 it throws errors.

Comment: Is your issue that you can't create a Win8.1 app on Win10 OR that you've created one on Win10 that matches one you previously created and installed on the same machine when it was running 8.1 and now you can't install the new one because of a package id issue? - I'm trying to understand your issue enough to a point where it could possibly be recreated.

Comment: Sure, to clarify: I used the standard windows store html/js template for windows universal apps on a windows 10 machine. it shows in the appx manifest the correct standards for windows 10+ apps. I cannot figure out how to get this app to work on windows 8.1 machines. it says it needs to be the 2010 schema which when I try to use an old appx manifest wont build..

Comment: So to test, create a hello world app in VS 2015 on windows 10 for html/js. Then create a package for it. Open that package on a windows 8.1 machine. run the powershell, see it complaining and not working.

Comment: Which template are you using? "Universal Windows" or "Windows 8.1"? Windows 10 Universal Apps can't run on Windows 8.1, you need use "Universal Windows 8.1" or "Windows 8.1" template for your project to build Windows 8.1 Apps.

Comment: There arent any provided that say they are for 8.1. I just went with the standard html/js template when choosing new project.

Comment: When creating new project, you may see templates like [this picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nm8A.png),  "Universal Windows" means this template is for Windows 10 Universal app and  "Windows 8.1" means this  template is for Windows 8.1 Store app. I created a new "Blank App(Windows 8.1)" project in VS2015 on Windows 10 and sideload this app package in another computer which install Windows 8.1 Enterprise, the app works well.